# How to navigate to other page

Tags: angular

I am developing an angular app. The current version is 6.0.9. I want to navigate to an individual product page if I click on a product in homepage products. But it navigates the page on the same page. Also, I don't want to display the discount if it is zero. I am using ngIf directive for this. But all the discounts are displayed as in the image.[My Homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcz77.jpg)

[What I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5i1Kn.jpg)

My code is:

component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="!discountPercent">
    <div class="col-md-3" *ngFor="let product of productList">
      <figure class="card card-product"> 
        <div class="starburst discount" id="star" #rotateEl>
          <span></span>
          <span>{{product.Discount}}%</span>
        </div>
        <div class="img-wrap">
         <a routerLink="/product-details"><img src="assets/{{ product.Image }}"></a> 
        </div>
        <div class="parent">
        <div class="block-ellipsis">
          <span>{{product.ProductName}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>

          <div class="price-wrap h5">
            <span class="price-new">Rs.{{product.DiscountedPrice}}</span> &nbsp;
            <del class="price-old">Rs.{{product.OriginalPrice}}</del>
          </div>
</figure>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Route.ts:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'product-details', component: ProductDetailsComponent}
];
```

component.ts

```
productList: any;
  discountPercent = 0;

ngOnInit() {
    this.productsService.getProducts()
    .then((response:Response) => {
      console.log(response);
      this.productList = response;
      this.discountPercent = this.productList.Discount;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

Comment: You must share your routes for helping us help you. Also if you don't share your component controller it's hard to tell you what to do. About discontPercent if you declared it as a number change the !discountPercent to "discountPercent !== 0"

Comment: I updated the question with the code..

Comment: Why did you put *ngIf="!discountPercent" outside of *ngfor? And also you can try this condition as *ngIf="discountPercent != 0".

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a component responsible for displaying an individual product.
Then define a route that goes to that component.

Here is a [link](https://angular.io/guide/router) that shows how to define angular routes

Comment: Is it possible to gave route without create a component??  I am created a component for individual product.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to solve your problem with displaying the 0% you should compare with a number.

```
<div *ngIf="discountPercent !== 0">
  ....
</div>
```

Secondly you have just one route, which is the route where you show all products so now you have to add a new route and a new component.

Route.ts

```
{ path: 'product-details', component: ProductDetailsComponent},
{ path: 'product-details/:id', component: ProductComponent}
```

This will make you have an individual page to each product. Now, to know which product are you seen you have the id of the product, which you pass it thru the URL. For example, if you want to see the information about product 22 you will have to navigate to "yourpage.com/product-details/22".

Once there, you'll have to recover the id in your new component (ProductComponent) from the URL parameters.

Product.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from "@angular/router";

export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
    public product: any;

    constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute ) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
       this.route.params.subscribe(
          params => {
            const id = +params['id']; // Recovering the id from URL
            this.loadProductInformation(id);
          }
       )
    }

    private loadProductInformation(id: number) {
       // Here you make the call to your service to get your product data

    }
}
```

Finally as you did in your ProductDetailsComponent you make some HTML to show the information.

Edit: I forgot that you have also to change the RouterLink in ProductDetailsComponent to navigate to the product ID. In order to do that you have to do something like `routerLink="/product-details/{{product.id}}"`

Comment: I was three component like header,home page products and footer .In app.component.html gave router respectively.I i click any page it display on the same page.I want to remove the home page products just show header and footer.navigate page should display on center

Comment: I'm not sure about what are you asking but you need to create the respective routes to each view and then in your app.component.ts you need a     <router-outlet></router-outlet> to load the components depending on the route

Comment: This is how i load my components in app.component.html                                                   <app-header></app-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <app-banner></app-banner>
  <app-products></app-products>
  <app-customer-feedback></app-customer-feedback>
  <app-footer></app-footer>

Comment: Then doesn't matter where you are in the application you will always see the app-products and the app-customer-feedback. I recommend you to take a look at the Tour of Heroes Angular  tutorial

Comment: I can't get you.. My question is if i want to navigate to individual page that page is added with the existing page. It is not displayed as an individual page

Comment: I already solved your question... You cannot pretend to navigate to an individual page where the only thing that is shown is your product information having your app.component like that. As I said, anywhere in your page you will have the app-product component  and the app-customer-feedback component. You have to change the structure of your components and for that the best thing you can do is read the Tour of Heroes

Comment: But,the other question i asked about displaying discount price is also not working..

Comment: I truly think that you need to cover the basics of angular. Each product need his own discount and inside the loop, when you show the discount you have to apply the *ngIf comparing the discount percentage of each product with 0. If it is different to 0 the span will be shown, otherwise not

Answer (score -1):

hmm, you have to code like this:

`import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
constructor(private router: Router) { }
this.router.navigate(['/your router']);`